# how block user to get into some page for admin

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

### how block user to get into some page for admin ASP.net C# MVC RAZOR

I already create user login and I would like to ask that how can I block some user to be not allow get into some page that I don't want?

---

For example, I got User A, B and C and I have Page 1 and 2.

What I want is:

when User A get login to my web, he can get into page 1 but he is not allow to get into page 2. In the other hand, if B get login, he can enter only page 2. And if C get login, he will can get bout page 1 and 2.

Now, I use sql server to keep the user data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Authorize` attribute to decorate your controller (or a method of your controller).

To do so you can refer to the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) msdn page.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is when the user log on the website, get his admin state from database too and keep it in session variable. For example the user A is the admin so he can visit every single page. His admin status is 1. If another user user B, log on the website, if his admin state is not equals to 1, just hide the links that would let him visit the page that he's not allowed to visit. Then you can provide different states : 1= admin, 2 = manager, 3 = visitor.
Just make conditions to display the links.